# Retrieving data from API in Excel 2016 ProPlus

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel document and I want to retrieve this data using this API (JSON)

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=USD

[toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf5ag.png)

From these buttons from the toolbar, I think I have to use "From Web".
But when I click on it, this window appears

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJeQU.png)

Then I paste the link from the API in there and it downloads the JSON file - then it redirects back to the default page of that window. So I think this is not the proper way to do it.

How can I import data from that API in Excel?